# Unity 2019.2.12 Tile palette missing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm missing **tile palette** feature. How do I get it? Am I missing any other features?

[image]

I've seen others have this similar issue, but I never really saw it get solved.

Also on school computer so can't really access the links they posted, but I heard they took you to downloads for tile palette, but if tile palette is in the unity manual why do I need to download it from some random site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **2019.2** and above, if you created a new Unity project, you will need to add the 2D Tilemap Editor package from the Unity Package Manager (under Window/Package Manager) to your project to be able to create Tiles and access the Tile Palette. If you created a new Unity project with the 2D template, the package will be added for you automatically. If you upgraded from a previous Unity version, the package will be automatically added as well.